# 500 server Error posting to Node server with Postman

Tags: node.js

I am not able to execute post request in postman.
It gives a internal server error. Here I am using localhost with phpmyadmin.

Here is my code for POST data using postman.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {

  const username = req.body.username
  const password = req.body.password
  const sql = "INSERT INTO `dataa`(`username`, `password`) VALUES (?, ?)"

  db.query(sql, [username, password], (err, rows, fields) => {
    if(!err)
    res.send(rows);
    else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Table name shouldn't be in quotation
Use like this

const sql = "INSERT INTO dataa('username','password') VALUES (?, ?)"

Answer (score 0):

```
     app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
       const username = req.body.username
       const password = req.body.password
       let payload={}
       payload.username=username
       payload.password=password
        var query = db.query('INSERT INTO dataa SET ?', payload, function (error, results, fields) {
          if (error) throw error;
          // Neat!
        });
        })
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined. This error comes

Comment: your body contain username ,just check with req.body ?

Comment: username is my attribute in phpmyadmin table, I can't understand "just check with req.body"..??

Comment: your body contains username or not like req.body should have "username":"somevalue","password":"somevalue"} just verify with.console.log(req.body)

Comment: again same error is occuring,i am using postman for this api and  nothing is coming in username

Comment: in your node js application const bodyParser = require('body-parser');app.use(bodyParser.json()); ,make sure you are using bodyparser